# How to escape apostrophe in Google Analytics Enhanced Ecommerce

Tags: google-analytics, escaping

Brands with an apostrophe were not appearing in my Google Analytics reports. This was my code:

```
<script>
    (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
        (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
                 m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
                })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
                ga('create', 'UA-52143532-4', 'auto');
            ga('require', 'ec');
    ga('ec:addProduct', {
                  'id': 'pay-q39-instead-of-q90-fo',                      'name': 'Pay Q39 instead of Q90 for haircut (2018-09-17)',          'category': 'Other',
      'brand': 'The Barber's Shop',           'variant': 'male',                    'price': '5.07'         });
    // Transaction level information is provided via an actionFieldObject.
    ga('ec:setAction', 'detail');           ga('send', 'event', 'ecommerce', 'detail');     </script>
```

The way I tried to fix it was by using the following code, simply by escaping the apostrophe:

Brands with an apostrophe were not appearing in my Google Analytics reports. This was my code:

```
<script>
    (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
        (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
                 m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
                })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
                ga('create', 'UA-52143532-4', 'auto');
            ga('require', 'ec');
    ga('ec:addProduct', {
                  'id': 'pay-q39-instead-of-q90-fo',                      'name': 'Pay Q39 instead of Q90 for haircut (2018-09-17)',          'category': 'Other',
      'brand': 'The Barber\'s Shop',          'variant': 'male',                    'price': '5.07'         });
    // Transaction level information is provided via an actionFieldObject.
    ga('ec:setAction', 'detail');           ga('send', 'event', 'ecommerce', 'detail');     </script>
```

I am simply using `'brand': 'The Barber\'s Shop'` instead of `'brand': 'The Barber's Shop'`. However, I still do not see data in Google Analytics about brands whose names have an apostrophe in it. Is this the correct way to escape apostrophes in Google Analytics? Thank you.

UPDATE 1: If Google Analytics does not like the `'brand': 'The Barber\'s Shop'` solution instead of `'brand': 'The Barber's Shop'`, then I am planning to write some code to remove any appearance of an apostrophe altogether and have `'brand': 'The Barbers Shop'` instead. It would surprise me though, if Google Analytics cannot not handle apostrophes somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may sounds silly, but have you tried something like the following?

```
<script>
    (function(i, s, o, g, r, a, m) {
        i["GoogleAnalyticsObject"] = r;
        i[r] = i[r] || function() {
            (i[r].q = i[r].q || []).push(arguments)
        }, i[r].l = 1 * new Date();
        a = s.createElement(o),
            m = s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];
        a.async = 1;
        a.src = g;
        m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m)
    })(window, document, "script", "//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js", "ga");
    ga("create", "UA-52143532-4", "auto");
    ga("require", "ec");
    ga("ec:addProduct", {
        "id": "pay-q39-instead-of-q90-fo",
        "name": "Pay Q39 instead of Q90 for haircut (2018-09-17)",
        "category": "Other",
        "brand": "The Barber's Shop",
        "variant": "male",
        "price": "5.07"
    });
    // Transaction level information is provided via an actionFieldObject.
    ga("ec:setAction", "detail");
    ga("send", "event", "ecommerce", "detail");
</script>
```

I replaced the single quotes with double quotes, this should avoid the confusion and "fix" the problem.

Comment: Interesting! I have not tried it and for now I think I am fine with having `'brand': 'The Barbers Shop'`, since in my reports I can easily understand that `The Barbers Shop` refers to `The Barber's Shop`. But in the future if I encounter another instance where I need to have an apostrophe, I will definitely try your solution. It makes sense. Still, I guess Google should be able to allow people to escape apostrophes by using `\`. Thank you F. Leone.

Comment: No bother, glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

See UPDATE 1 in the question. I ended up removing apostrophes altogether, so I have this now:

```
'brand': 'The Barbers Shop'
```

It still surprises me though, to think that Google Analytics cannot handle apostrophes, if that is the case.